# Activity lifecycle on Orientation change

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-lifecycle

I have an activity MainActivity. MainActivity extends a CustomActivity which extends Activity class.
Inside CustomActivity, I have overridden the onStop in a way, whenever onStop is called, the app cleares all cache and shuts down.
****No issue till here****

Now I have a pdf viewer in the app and I want the pdf to auto adjust whenever I do an orientation change. So, I want the activity to recreate everytime a change the orientation. What happens now, is whenever I rotate the screen, the app onStop is called first (and becuase of CustomActivity onStop, the app gets closed) and the MainActivity onCreate is never being called.

This might be the most foolish question ever, I know,

1. but is there anyway, I can stop the onStop() being called whenever I do rotate the screen even though I want the onCreate to be called again.
2. Is there any lifecycle method between onStop() and onCreate() that I can use.

P.S. - I don't want onConfigurationChange() method to be called as I want the activity to be recreated.

Comment: From what I get, either make the `Activity` with a pdf viewer not extend `CustomActivity` or move the "shut down" part of `CustomActivity` in a separate method and call it from each descendant `Activity`'s `onStop()` except for the one with a pdf viewer so that letting it to be recreated as per the `Activity` lifecycle.

Comment: Or make the `CustomActivity` that only "cleares all cache" in `onStop()` and another one that extends `CustomActivity` and "shuts down" in `onStop()` (let's call it `CustomActivity2`). Then make "a-pdf-viewer" Activity extend `CustomActivity`, while the others extend `CustomActivity2`.